# Erro 404 - "Not Found" ao tentar executar um projeto Java com SpringBoot no PostMan

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc, postman

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Java SpringBoot utilizando o padrão MVC e gerenciando as requisições API via PostMan. Entretanto, ao tentar fazer uma requisição POST ou GET, ele aponta o erro:

```
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found
```

Segue como está atualmente a configuração do projeto:

[Método Main no Java SpringBoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hkz0.png)

[Requisição no PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bq9J.png)

Classe Controller:

```
package Controller;

import Model.Usuario;
import UsuarioRepository.UsuarioRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuarios")
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @GetMapping("/assessment")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Usuario> listarUsuarios(){
        return usuarioRepository.findAll();
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @PostMapping
    public Usuario criarUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario){
        return usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Usuario atualizarUsuario(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Usuario usuarioAtualizado){
        return usuarioRepository.findById(id)
                .map(usuario -> {
                    usuario.setNome(usuarioAtualizado.getNome());
                    usuario.setEmail(usuarioAtualizado.getEmail());
                    return usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
                })
                .orElseThrow();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deletarUsuario(@PathVariable Long id){
        usuarioRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Arquivo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gerenciamento de Usuários</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>Gerenciamento de Usuários</h2>
    <form id="usuarioForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar Usuário</button>
    </form>

    <table class="table mt-5">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="usuariosTableBody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS e jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Função para carregar os usuários da API
    function carregarUsuarios() {
        fetch('/usuarios')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                const usuariosTableBody = document.getElementById('usuariosTableBody');
                usuariosTableBody.innerHTML = '';

                data.forEach(usuario => {
                    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    tr.innerHTML = `
                        <td>${usuario.id}</td>
                        <td>${usuario.nome}</td>
                        <td>${usuario.email}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="editarUsuario(${usuario.id})">Editar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deletarUsuario(${usuario.id})">Excluir</button>
                        </td>
                    `;
                    usuariosTableBody.appendChild(tr);
                });
            });
    }

    // Função para adicionar ou atualizar um usuário
    function adicionarUsuario(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

        fetch('/usuarios', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ nome, email })
        })
        .then(() => {
            document.getElementById('nome').value = '';
            document.getElementById('email').value = '';
            carregarUsuarios();
        });
    }

    // Função para editar um usuário
    function editarUsuario(id) {
        // Implemente conforme necessário
        console.log('Editar usuário com ID:', id);
    }

    // Função para deletar um usuário
    function deletarUsuario(id) {
        if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir este usuário?')) {
            fetch(`/usuarios/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
            .then(() => carregarUsuarios());
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('usuarioForm').addEventListener('submit', adicionarUsuario);
    carregarUsuarios();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.CRUDMySQL</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRUD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CRUD</name>
    <description>CRUD com MySQL</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```